# Multiple Conditions in a Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column

I am very new to creating formulas in a SP column, so hopefully I explain it accurately.

I have a requirement to have a custom number auto-generate to display (ACR Number) PF-IS-VH-17-000.  1st field cat.(2 options), 2nd = business unit, 3rd = location (3options)and then YY-sequential number (3 digits).

This is my formula:

```
=IF(Category="Project File","PF-IS-"&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID),IF(Category="Change Control","CC-IS-"&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID)))
```

My problem is I do not know how to get the 3rd field in there, the associated column in a CHOICE column with 3 locations to choose from.  Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked Great!

```
=IF(Category="Project File","PF-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"-yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID),IF(Category="Change Control","CC-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"-yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID)))
```

Comment: Please if this formula worked for you, Please don't forget to **Mark** your answer as the accepted answer to close this question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the choice into the formula as similar as a text column.

Here is my formula with choice column.

```
=Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")
```

In the formula Location is a choice column and Created is an out of the box Created date column.

It displays the result as below.

[image]

Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: This?      =IF(Category="Project File","PF-IS-"=Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID),IF(Category="Change Control","CC-IS-"=Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID)))

Comment: It gives me a ACR Number of "0"

Comment: try like this `=IF(Category="Project File","PF-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",R‌​EPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(‌​ID))),ID),IF(Categor‌​y="Change Control","CC-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-‌​",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-L‌​EN(ID))),ID)))`

Comment: I hope Location is your choice field. If not replace with your field.

Comment: Yes, it is.  However, I am receiving a syntax error.  I am verifying placement of paren/commas/""

Comment: Can you post your updated formula

Comment: =IF(Category="Project File","PF-IS-"=Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID),IF(Category="Change Control","CC-IS-"=Location&TEXT(Created,"yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID)))

Comment: No error message, but still "0" end result

Comment: You should not use the =Location. '=' symbol is only a starting point of my formula. See my above comment how it has been modified. And if the Location is not a valid field then it throw error

Comment: Yes, I don't know how I missed that.    Thank you, thank you!

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Yes, perfectly. Example: CC-IS-VH-17-004

Comment: Glad to hear that. Mark as answer to help others.